# Control another tab bar controller's view to root view by Swift code

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, root

I am new to swift code. I got a question but can't find out the solution for few days and also didn't got the answer from web, too.

I have an app and the root view controller is a UITabBarController. I have two UINavigationControllers controlled by this UITabBarViewController. Each UINavigationController with some UITableViewController and ViewController inside.

My question is that if I press a UIButton in anywhere, I want all UINavigationController go back to root view (the default state when I startup the app). Is it possible to done this by swift code?

Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reach your rootViewController from anywhere like this

```
  var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  let myTabBarView = (appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarViewController)!
  self.presentViewController(myTabBarView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but still has an error: 2015-06-17 17:50:11.318 TabBar[71358:16459689] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <UITabBarController: 0x7fbc91e844e0>.'